# How to find out the converse, inverse and contrapositive of a propositional logic with whenever using whenever?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, propositional-calculus, conditional-expectation

My college teacher provided a question in an exam where I had to find the converse, inverse and contrapositive of the sentence "I come to class whenever there is going to be a quiz" and instead of using "if" I answered the questions using "whenever" but my answers were treated as incorrect. This question was already solved in several websites using "if" and I want to know if it's okay to answer with whenever and if it is okay why mine is wrong or if it even is. Here are my answers:

Question statement: I come to class whenever there is going to be a quiz.

Converse: There is going to be a quiz whenever I come to class.
Contrapositive: There is not going to be a quiz whenever I do not come to class.
Inverse: I do not come to class whenever there is not going to be a quiz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the original sentence contained 'whenever' instead of 'if', then I would say you did everything correct.

Please note though that 'whenever' is sometimes used to express an 'if and only if', i.e. A Biconditional. So, if the original sentence contained an 'if' then maybe that is why you were marked incorrectly. But if the original contained 'whenever', then I would say that expressing the converse, inverse, and contrapositive using 'whenever' as well would be the exact safe thing to do!